# Group pairs by a second value, and map it where the key is the second element and a value is a list of first elements associated with the second

Tags: kotlin, lambda, group-by

As I mentioned in the title. I would like to group List of Pairs by the second value.
I came up with a code below that works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a possibility to do it more elegant using lambdas.

```
val data = mapOf(
        Pair("a1", listOf("b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5")),
        Pair("a2", listOf("b1", "b7", "b8", "b9", "b10")),
        Pair("a3", listOf("b6", "b7", "b8", "b9", "b10")),
        Pair("a4", listOf("b6", "b7", "b8", "b9", "b11")),
        Pair("a5", listOf("b6", "b2", "b12", "b9", "b13"))
)

val map = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<String>>()

data.forEach { (k, v) ->
    v.forEach {
        if (map.containsKey(it)) {
            map[it]?.add(k)
        } else {
            map[it] = mutableListOf(k)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: something like `data.asIterable().groupBy { ... }`?

Answer (score 1):

According to your given example, the expected result is

> {b1=[a1, a2], b2=[a1, a5], b3=[a1], b4=[a1], b5=[a1], b7=[a2, a3, a4], b8=[a2, a3, a4], b9=[a2, a3, a4, a5], b10=[a2, a3], b6=[a3, a4, a5], b11=[a4], b12=[a5], b13=[a5]}

You could expand the given data structure in a way that every element from your second element is being associated to the first element. But be aware that this results in additional space. Grouping becomes easier then:

```
data.entries
    .flatMap { (k, v) -> v.map { k to it } }
    .groupBy(keySelector = Pair<*, *>::second, valueTransform = Pair<*, *>::first) //group by list element, only add key to group
```

The iterative approach can be simplified to:

```
val map = mutableMapOf<String, List<String>>().withDefault { listOf() }

for ((k, v) in data) {
    for (e in v) map[e] = map.getValue(e) + k
}
```

Comment: This code does exactly what I want. Thank you very much

Comment: @user1359660 if the answer solves your problem, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it :)